# Best practice for Python typing out of dictionary (self.fields type in Django ModelForm)

Tags: python, django, mypy, python-typing

I have a form like this

```
class MerchantBrandsForm(forms.Form):
    brands = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=True, queryset=None)

    def __init__(self: merchant: Merchant, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['brands'].queryset = merchant.brands.all()
```

But I have an error with `mypy` with the queryset as `fields` has a type `Dict[str, Field]`, which cause `error: "Field" has no attribute "queryset"`.

I know I can cast the `fields` using `cast` or ignore the typing, but I don't think this is a *clean* solution. What is the best way to assign `brands` queryset without ignoring the type or using `cast` function?

Comment: First, write a feature-request to `django-stubs`, if it is not there: using plugin-generated `typing.TypedDict` should resolve this problem. Then, if you want to do it in code and cannot help writing mypy plugin for that, declare `fields: SomeTypedDict` on form class, where `SomeTypedDict` is a `TypedDict` with explicit fields definition (`name: type`). You'll need to ignore that line, because `TypedDict` is not compatible with `dict`, but it'll work in all other places. TypedDict's can be inherited.

Comment: I would love to write the feature, but I'm not really sure where I can start because AFAIK you can't determine the `TypedDict` fields at type checking. The only thing I think of for now is just to add a generic to the `Form` for that `TypedDict`. I guess your solution would be the "most cleanest" way for now https://gist.github.com/andraantariksa/e524c2b7ba2044ecd71aeb16ce922f36.

Comment: I suspect generic will be a really awkward solution, because explicitly enumerating fields is not what users do want (I have ~80 forms in last project, enumerating fields twice would've bored me very much). I mean using plugin - the same thing that does awesome work on, for example, typechecking fields lookup (like `mymodel__myfield__mydependecy__date__isnull = True`) - to generate this TypedDict and assign to `form.fields`. Until this is implemented, I agree your sample is a most clean solution. The main problem is DRY violation, here's why plugin is required.